# Execute spark jobs in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, pyspark, ml-studio

I am trying to run some spark scripts using execute python script in azure ML studio. And getting an error saying 
`unable to import spark libraries`

Basically i am trying to create web services using ML studio for the models that are developed.

Is it possible or feasible to run spark jobs using ML studio?

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.